# Not able to return data from controller to view in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am sending content from my `view` to the `controller` through `AJAX`.It seems to be working well as it hits the `action method` and executes properly. However I am not able to get the data returned from `action` back in the `view`.

Is It missing something?

Note: *I did try to debug the code, but once it goes through the action method it does not come back to the function.*

Follows the *AJAX* code:

```
function CategoryChanged() {
    var value = $("#ContentType").val();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Home")',
        type: "POST",            
        data: { code: value }
    }).done(function (data) {
       console.log(data)
        var response = data;                
        if (data != null) {
            $("#Content").val(data.content);
        }
    });

    };

</script>
```

And the controller code:

```
 [HttpPost]      
    public ActionResult Action(int code)
    {
        using (SERVFL_DMSEntities db = new SERVFL_DMSEntities())
        {
            var cust1 = db.HomePageCustomizations.Where(r => r.IsPublic == true && r.ContentType == code).OrderByDescending(r => r.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            string cust2 = cust1.Content;
            return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = new { Content = cust2}
            }; 
        }
    }
```

I have checked the Network on the console and it indicates I am receiving the data. The line console.log(data) does contain the required data.

Possible Issue - Having seen a lot of such questions, I have seen responses like change URL to `/Home/Action`. Is that actually an issue or it does not matter?

Comment: Can you debug the JS code to see what `data` actually contains?

Comment: in the done function: why are you setting up `var response`, then setting `vdata` and then using `response` again?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen During debug,the JS code is never hit once the Action method is completed.

Comment: @Finn Mistake on my part, will change it.

Comment: remove `dataType: "json",` from your script and try then

Comment: @SunilKumar Does not change anything, the issue persists.

Comment: Your posting back and object with property named `Content ` so its `$("#Content").val(response.Content );` (although there is no need for `var response = data;` and you may as well just use `$("#Content").val(data.Content);`)

Comment: What issue you are getting in browser console ?

Comment: And you can simplify the controller code to `return Json(new { Content = cust2 });` but your `.FirstOrDefault()` can return `null` meaning `string cust2 = cust1.Content;` would throw an exception - you need to test for `null` first

Comment: @SunilKumar Browser console shows no errors.

Comment: When in doubt, use a Network tool, like Fiddler, to view the returned payload.

Comment: put your HTML also where you are calling the function `CategoryChanged`

Comment: @StephenMuecke All those would be an issue if the control gets back to the function after the Action result. But my breakpoint on .done is never hit.

Comment: Note: It will not map `Data` to `data` automatically in that direction.Change to `data = new {...`

Comment: try one more thing : 
Remove `type: "POST",` from your script and Remove `[HttpPost]` from your ActionResult ...

Comment: See the edit to my last note (and check your browser console for errors - I assume your controller is throwing an exception)

Comment: @SunilKumar. Do not remove `[HttpPost]` - that would throw an exception

Comment: @StephenMuecke Will check if that is an issue.

Comment: try adding `.fail()`,  to check if something went wrong

Comment: @StephenMuecke The browser console does not throw any errors.

Comment: @ShekharPankaj I did add the .fail() to check if there are any issues. But my problem though is that the control never goes back to the function once the Action Result is executed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code (except for your use of `response.data` and not catching a possible exception) although it can be simplified. Try using `success: function(data) { console.log(data); }` in lieu of `.done` and change the controller to `return Json(cust2);`

Comment: How is CategoryChanged called?

Comment: @epascarello On a dropdown change event

Comment: So do you see the request in the network tab of the console? What do you see?

Comment: @epascarello Yes I can see the request on the consoleand it is pointing to the right actionresult. It also has a response header. Any other information from the console that would be needed?

Comment: Could it simply be that `.val(response)` doesn't do anything? Try `alert`-ing the result instead?

Comment: @The_Outsider how was your issue resolved!!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below code works for you..

**the AJAX code:**

```
function CategoryChanged() {
    var value = $("#ContentType").val();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { code: value }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        $('#Content').html(data);
    });
};
```

**And the controller code:**

```
[HttpPost]      
    public ActionResult Action(int code)
    {
        using (SERVFL_DMSEntities db = new SERVFL_DMSEntities())
        {
            var cust1 = db.HomePageCustomizations.Where(r => r.IsPublic == true && r.ContentType == code).OrderByDescending(r => r.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            string cust2 = cust1.Content;
            return Content(cust2, "text/html"); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the data using the `Json()` method:

```
[HttpPost]      
    public ActionResult Action(int code)
    {
        using (SERVFL_DMSEntities db = new SERVFL_DMSEntities())
        {
            var cust1 = db.HomePageCustomizations.Where(r => r.IsPublic == true && r.ContentType == code).OrderByDescending(r => r.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            string cust2 = cust1.Content;
            return Json(new { result = cust2 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
        }
    }
```

And in your View:

```
function CategoryChanged() {
    var value = $("#ContentType").val();
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { code: value }
    }).done(function (data) {
        if(data.result != undefined){
            $('#Content').html(data.result);
        }
    });
};
```